# Cannot connect to MySQL server (111 Connection refused)

Tags: python, mysql, docker

So I am getting this error when attempting to connect to MySQL using docker-compose up:

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111 Connection refused)
```

Using the command `SHOW VARIABLES` I saw that bind_address' value is:

```
 bind_address                                             | *
```

Meaning it should bind to any address right? So why is this error coming up then?

I am at a loss as all of the research I did said that usually the bind-address variable is set to localhost. However, as mine is not, I'm stuck at what else to look at.

my docker-compose.yml file if that makes any difference:

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    build: 
      context: ./dev
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "32000:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
  - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
```

Comment: From the point of view of the `app` container, `localhost` is itself, not the outer host or a different container.  How are you configuring the database location?

Comment: Have you tried:

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "32000:3306"
    expose:
      - "3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
  - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro

Comment: the database will be stored on the local storage. I have also tried the above configuration but it does not change anything with the error